# Where to initialize a reusable object in a ParDo?

Tags: apache-beam

An example of my ParDo in my beam job (running with Dataflow runner):

```
class StreamEventToJsonConverter : DoFn<MyClass, String>() {
    @ProcessElement
    fun processElement(@Element element: MyClass, receiver: OutputReceiver<String>) {
        val gson = Gson()
        val jsonValue = gson.toJson(element)
        receiver.output(jsonValue)
    }
}
```

My question is: should I initialize the Gson object inside of the processElement function?

Is it only initialized once per worker or everytime a new element enters the function (seems to be overkilled)?

Given that the Gson object is not serializable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Turned out I can do via a [DoFn.Setup](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.Setup.html) function:

> Annotation for the method to use to prepare an instance for processing bundles of elements.
>
> This is a good place to initialize transient in-memory resources, such as network connections. The resources can then be disposed in DoFn.Teardown.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms)

> A given **DoFn** instance generally gets invoked one or more times to
>   process some arbitrary bundle of elements. However, Beam doesn’t
>   guarantee an exact number of invocations; it may be invoked multiple
>   times on a given worker node to account for failures and retries. As
>   such, you can cache information across multiple calls to your
>   processing method, but if you do so, make sure the implementation does
>   not depend on the number of invocations.

Based on this, seems the DoFn is executed each time and according to your use case, the Gson object will be initialized different times in a worker node